# Get a break in an outline on a div

Tags: html, css

I have an outline around my div and i want a break on the right border [(how I want it to look like)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N95EJ.png)

My HTML:

```
<div class="carouseldiv w-75 mx-auto pt-5 customer-box-shadow">
CONTENT
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.customer-box-shadow {
outline: 2px solid $red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mask and you will have transparency as well. I replaced outline with an inner shadow

```css
.customer-box-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px inset red; /* you can also use border */
  padding:50px;
  -webkit-mask:
     /* adjust the 60% to control the height of the cut */
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) right/2px 60% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
          mask-composite: exclude;
}


body {
  background:linear-gradient(90deg,#ccc,#fff)
}
```

```html
<div class="customer-box-shadow">
  CONTENT
</div>
```

If you want to keep using outline consider `clip-path`

```css
.customer-box-shadow {
  --d: 2px; /* outline border */
  --c: 60%; /* the cut */
  outline: var(--d) solid red;
  padding:50px;
  clip-path:
   polygon(calc(-1*var(--d)) calc(-1*var(--d)),
          calc(100% + var(--d)) calc(-1*var(--d)),
          calc(100% + var(--d)) calc(50% - var(--c)/2),
          100% calc(50% - var(--c)/2),
          100% calc(50% + var(--c)/2),
          calc(100% + var(--d)) calc(50% + var(--c)/2),
          calc(100% + var(--d)) calc(100% + var(--d)),
          calc(-1*var(--d)) calc(100% + var(--d)))
}


body {
  background:linear-gradient(90deg,#ccc,#fff)
}
```

```html
<div class="customer-box-shadow">
  CONTENT
</div>
```

Comment: While this is a beautiful solution, does it work with `outline` as per OP's requirements as well?

Comment: @connexo added another solution for outline

Comment: It's great to see what is possible with CSS, yet I bet 99.9998% of CSS developers would have no clue how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

hide the border with another div, like this:

```css
.bordered{
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px gray solid;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay{
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12.5px;
  top: calc(50% - 12.5px);
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="bordered">
  content ...
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

No change in markup required. Use a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) `::after` to cover the unwanted parts of the outline:

```css
.customer-box-shadow {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.customer-box-shadow::after {
  background-color: white;
  content: "";
  bottom: 30px; /* you might want a percentage here */
  right: -2px;
  width: 2px;
  top: 30px; /* you might want a percentage here */
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="customer-box-shadow">
  content ...
</div>
```